# Closure Compiler: JSC_PARSE_ERROR '[' expected

Tags: google-closure-compiler

Closure Compiler throws a parse error when trying to compile the following code.

```
obj = {
       'on-save'() { return 1; } 
      };
```

The returned error is

```
stdin:2: ERROR - Parse error. '[' expected
'on-save'() {
^
```

Is this a bug in parser, as the same code gets executed in node?

Comment: Well normally I'd expect to see `obj = { ['on-save']() { return 1; }};` which apparently the compiler does too.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and it worked fine. But, why does the above syntax throw error? Is it because closure compiler prefers to enclose literal property keys with square brackets or is this an unexpected bug? @ChadKillingsworth